# Android: Limit the number of return characters a user can enter in an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know you can set an `EditText`'s `maxLines` to be something like `5`. But how can I actually limit how many return characters (i.e. when a user presses the return key on their softkeyboard) an EditText can have?

I basically do not want my user doing this in my EditText:

```
_##___________________####
#####________________#####
######______________######
_#######____________######
___########________#######
____#########_____#######_
______########____#######_
_______#########__#######_
___________######_#####___
______________########____
________#############_____
______#################___
_____###(__)############___
____###################___
___#####################__
____###################___
_____#################____
_________##########_______
________#############_____
______################____
_____####/ ######## \####___
____####/ ########## \####__
___####/ ############ \###_
___###/ ############# |###_
___###| ############## /##_
___###\ ############# /##___
____##################____
_____################_____
______##############______
_______############_______
_______############_______
_______############_______
_______############_______
_______#####__#####_______
_______####____####_______
______#####____#####______
___########____########___
___########____########___
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and check amount of return characters:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int amountOfReturns = s.length() - s.toString().replace("\n", "").length();

            //Here you can check amountOfReturns > MAX_RETURN_COUNT
            //and do what you need, for example, prevent to change the text
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
editText.setText(s.toString().substring(5));
}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
   }
  });
```

Comment: This limits the overall length of the string to 5 characters.  That's not what was asked.

Comment: Don't ask me, ask the OP.  It's stated in the problem description.